URL length for notifications
We starting to have an issue with users.
They are creating to long folders with subfolders and then file name.
Problem is even when they get notification from One drive that that file is not syncing because of the URL length, they just ignore click ok, One drive is shutting down and then is a problem.
My question is can we create some kind of notification in MS Graph with power automate to get notification if URL is too long?

If the users are currently ignoring the OneDrive default notifications on file/folder path length, they would as well ignore the new notification that you're looking for. Better educate the users as the restrictions vary how OneDrive is used. See MS Support Link on OneDrive

is there a way to automatically remove problematic link?

You could potentially run Power Automate Flow and check each file path length, and if it exceeds the limit, move the file towards the root folder, or rename it to shorten the folder/file name. There are plenty examples online as to how you could work with OneDrive in Power Automate

Thanks I will try, maybe I am blind but I didnt see any links when I was searching regarding that subject
